# PAW - body value field is only a textfield instead of textarea

Tags: paw-app

few versions ago i had a "textarea"-like field in the Body->Parameter[value]. Noe it is only a text field, which is not very handy, if you try to manage JSON requests for example. Any idea how to change this ?

thx
Martin

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean? You're trying to have a long field inside a Body > Form URL-Encoded? If the long text is a JSON, I recommend you to use the inline JSON editor, in any field, start typing "JSON" and you'll be offered to add a "JSON Dynamic Value", click on the inserted token, and you'll be able to visually edit a JSON document.